# Is SSL secure for AJAX calls?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl

I have a website developed using JQuery and PHP. All database requests (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) are made using AJAX calls. I realized that these requests can be tracked on debug environment of browsers. I decided to use SSL, but I don't know whether SSL makes these requests secure. So should I use SSL?

Thanks.

Comment: SSL would help, but it doesn't solve issues like Cross-side Scripting.  You should research about CSRF solutions and other things to secure your site.

Comment: SSL doesn't help you at all against people using their browser's dev tools. SSL only encrypts the channel. If your Javascript is doing raw SQL, you should be worried indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL can not stop brower to track the information. SSL comes into the picture only when data are passsed from client to server on wire... Role of SSL is to prevent the data from hacker if someone is trying to fetch the data when data is travelling between client and server.